# I have a question about Query: FLS Create

Tags: apex

I had received "This query looks for sObject Create operations that are performed without checking for isCreatable()"

Here is my code:

```
public static void insertData(DataWrapper wrapper) {

    List<DataRow> dataList = wrapper.dataList;
    for(Integer i=0 ;i < dataList.size();i++){
        DataRow data = dataList[i];
        starfarmer__Application__c application = new starfarmer__Application__c();
        application.starfarmer__FieldCategory__c = data.fieldCategory;
        ....
        insert application;
    }
}
```

--> so, how can i fix issue about message error "This query looks for sObject Create operations that are performed without checking for isCreatable()"?

Thanks for help!

Thanks for your help, please help me more:

I have code:

public static String getWhereClause(FilterSearch filters){

```
String whereClause = '';
Integer cropsId = filters.CropsId;
Integer diseaseWeedDraftId = filters.DiseaseWeedDraftId;
Integer methodUseId = filters.MethodUseId;
Integer activeIngredientId = filters.ActiveIngredientId;
Integer useId = filters.UseId;
String[] criteria = new List<String>{};
if (cropsId!=null && cropsId!=0) {
    criteria.add('starfarmer1__crops_id__c = :cropsId');
}
if (diseaseWeedDraftId!=null && diseaseWeedDraftId!=0) {
    criteria.add('starfarmer1__disease_weed_draft_id__c = :diseaseWeedDraftId');
}
if (methodUseId!=null && methodUseId!=0) {
    criteria.add('starfarmer1__method_use_id__c = :methodUseId');
}
if (activeIngredientId!=null && activeIngredientId!=0) {
    criteria.add('starfarmer1__active_ingredient_id__c = :activeIngredientId');
}
if (useId!=null && useId!=0) {
    criteria.add('starfarmer1__use_id__c = :useId');
}
if (criteria.size() > 0) {
    whereClause = 'WHERE ' + String.join(criteria, ' AND ');
}
return whereClause;
```

}

List<starfarmer__salesforce_regist_custom__x> rapcTmps = Database.query(CreateQuery.getRegistNumberDistinctOfRegistApplyPartCustomByFiltersQuery(whereClause));

public static String getRegistNumberDistinctOfRegistApplyPartCustomByFiltersQuery(String whereClause) {
return 'SELECT ExternalId, FROM starfarmer__salesforce_regist_custom__x ' + whereClause + ' AND ExternalId > :exId ORDER BY ExternalId ASC LIMIT :limitValueSelect';
}

I received message: "This query detects user controlled input entering the structure of a SOQL query in Apex. Unlike queries sent via the REST/SOAP API, queries in Apex do not enforce CRUD/FLS checks, and therefore letting the user inject their own SOQL code can lead to unauthorized data access. This is even true if the user can only influence fields in WHERE clauses. To fix this vulnerability, make sure that 1) user controlled data that is in a quoted context is entered into the query via a bound variable, or is otherwise sanitized with String.escapeSingleQuotes(). 2) For data that is not quoted it must be of a safe data type, such as integer or Id. 3) All other user data must be checked by manually performing CRUD/FLS checks or matching against a whitelist. This may be a false positive if you perform the sanitization outside of the detected dataflow or if the fieldtype is only controlled by a privileged account (custom settings)."

What do i need change with ' + whereClause + '

Comment: Bsically it's asking you to make sure that the current user can write to `starfarmer__FIeldCategory__c` and any other fields on `starfarmer__Application__c` as well as ensuring they have the create permission for the `starfarmer__Application__c ` object.

You can get all this information from the various describe methods.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To answer the first question, you should check the CRUD permissions of the user before attempting to perform any DML:

```
public static void insertData(DataWrapper wrapper) {
  // Check CRUD before insert.
  if(!sObjectType.starfarmer__Application__c.isCreateable()) {
    return;
  }
```

As a side note, do not insert in a loop, you'll get in to trouble in large data volumes:

```
public static void insertData(DataWrapper wrapper) {
    if(!sObjectType.starfarmer__Application__c.isCreateable()) {
        return;
    }
    List<DataRow> dataList = wrapper.dataList;
    starfarmer__Application__c[] applications = new starfarmer__Application__c[0];
    for(Integer i=0 ;i < dataList.size();i++){
        DataRow data = dataList[i];
        starfarmer__Application__c application = new starfarmer__Application__c();
        application.starfarmer__FieldCategory__c = data.fieldCategory;
        //....
        applications.add(application);
    }
    insert applications;
}
```

Comment: hi bro,

i had added your code but when i run "sfdx scanner:run" for local, i received message about Validate CRUD permission before SOQL/DML operation